# Is there a word or expression for "being comically famous"?

Tags: word-choice

Let me cite an example: Consider the CEO of this [website](http://lingscars.com).

She was widely known for the worst website on the internet. (She received awards for the same too).

But still, she is a celebrity but in a comical way. So, is there a word for that? Like, we use "notorious" for negatively famous!

Comment: "Internet famous" is an expression I see out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Laughingstock" has most of the meaning you want.  But a laughingstock is not necessarily famous.  A person can be the laughingstock of a small town, and not be known outside that town.

Comment: The connotation of "laughingstock" is that it was unintentional.  If it was on purpose--in order to be famous--the term would not apply.  For instance, [Psy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gangnam_Style) would not be considered a "laughingstock".